# Running Correlation in a For loop in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

I am trying to run a correlation in R in a for loop for about 14 data frames. The code works outside the for loop (without the concatenation) but not in the for loop.Gives me the error *"non-numeric argument to binary operator"*

[Image showing one of the data frames in the for loop that the correlation is being run on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQf7b.png)

```
#for loop to go through each crime type

    y<- unique(crimeSummary$cType) #To get the types of crime that I am trying to the run the corr on. 
    for(i in 1:length(y)){
      cor.test(paste("mergedpoW"+y+"$total.x", sep = "."), paste("mergedpoW"+y+"$total.y",sep = "."))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval(parse())` to evaluate strings as code. For example:

```
y <- unique(iris$Species) 
species_means <- rep(NA, 3)
for(i in 1:length(y)){
  string <- paste0("mean(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species=='", y[i], "'])")
  print(string)
  species_means[i] <- eval(parse(text=string))
}
print(species_means)
```

And a couple of quick points:

- You can't use `+` for string concatenation in (base) R. So in your case, replace the `+`s with commas -- `paste("mergedpoW", y, "$total.x", sep = ".")` (btw, should `sep` be `""`? in the example?)
- There's easier/cleaner ways to summarize multiple data frames -- e.g. you can collect all the df's into a list, and then use `lapply(df_list, your_summary_function)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks, not sure what's happening in "species_means <- rep(NA, 3)"..could you please explain?....to answer your question about 'sep', I put the "." there to compensate for the "." bit in the data frame.

Comment: my most recent looks as below                                                                       y<- unique(crimeSummary$cType)
        for(i in 1:length(y)){
          string1 <- paste0("mergedpoW",".",y[i],sep="")
          string2 <- paste0(string1,"$total.x",sep="")
          string3 <- paste0(string1,"$total.y",sep="")
          cor.test(eval(parse(text=string2)), eval(parse(text=string3)))
          
        }

Comment: the `species_means <- rep(NA, 3)` is just creating an empty vector to catch the results (each slot gets filled by `species_means[i] <- ...`). so when the loop is done then the values you want will be in `species_means`